# What is wrong with my subscription method on my route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Can someone see why the route is not subscribing to the publication. `Profiles = new Meteor.Collection('profiles');`

The mongo database does have documents in this collection,  but the browser console still has a count of 0 in Profiles collection.

I am trying to tell the router, "subscribe to user-profile publication, when you are ready, render the 'profile' template. I also named the route 'profile.'

Now I have noticed that after typing`sub = Meteor.subscribe('user-profile');` and then `sub.ready();` I get the count of the collection. Otherwise the path is not subscribed. This behaviour has not occurred before.

lib/router.js

```
Router.plugin('loading', {loadingTemplate: 'Loading'});

Router.route('user/profile', {
name: 'profile',
waitOn: function () {
 // return one handle, a function, or an array
 return Meteor.subscribe('user-profile');
 },

action: function () {
 // this.ready() is true if all items returned from waitOn are ready
 if (this.ready())
 this.render('profile');
 else
 this.render('Loading');
}
});
```

server.js:

```
Meteor.publish('user-profile', function () { 
return Profiles.find({userId: this.userId});
});
```

userId is a field in the Profiles collection. This profiles doc id is stored within the user.profile.experiences array for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.userId` is a function which returns the `_id`, not the `_id` itself, and you can't pass a function over DDP anyway.  It should be:

```
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('user-profile', Meteor.userId());
}
```

Comment: So in the publish function, should I return Profiles.find({}, {$in: {userId: Meteor.user.profile().experiences}});  // this references the array of Profile doc ids and then remove the parameters I passed into the pub/sub?

Comment: @CodeCandy, what are you storing in `userId` variable in `profile` collection?

Comment: I am storing Meteor.userId() in the method.

Comment: I removed all parameters for argument sake and published all docs like this//  Profiles.find({});  // this is still does not work

Comment: As always with pub/sub, check you have docs on the server using Mongo shell, check to see if you have docs on the client using the console, try running `sub = Meteor.subscribe...` in the console and check `sub.ready()` to see if your subscription is actually ready.  This is all in the docs.

Comment: A brilliant tip. I checked and it is ready. I then checked Profiles.find().count(); but this returns 0. The mongo shell shows 2 documents db.profiles.find().count();

Comment: @richsil - Yes, I removed the parameters, reset my project and now it is showing up. This is strange. It shows the count to be 2 on the browser console. Thanks for the earlier tip. Strange

Comment: @richsilv, I noticed that every time I do the count of the collection in the console, I get 0, but after I type sub = Meteor.subscribe('user-profile'); and then sub.ready(); I get the count of the collection. This is very strange. Thats why it seemed earlier that I may have made a typo or something but my code has been correct all along

Comment: I had to add the action to establish when the subscription is ready.